# I'm getting an error status of 400 in server side but getting a 200 status in client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm trying to build a login authentication and when the user inputs correctly, it should go to the home page but if not, it should send him to the login page. I've done this by checking the status of 200 and 400. When I input an incorrect username, the server side does return a code of 400. But the server side not and it still redirects me to the home page even if the user is incorrect. Why can that be due to?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './login.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";


function Login() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)

    const history = useHistory()


    const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
      setUsername(e.target.value)
    }

    const onChangePassword = (e) => {
      setPassword(e.target.value)
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()

      const users = {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
      axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/login', users)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    }

    const loginUser = () => {
      axios.get("http://localhost:4000/users/login", {
        withCredentials: true
      }).then(res => {
        if(res.status === 200) {
          setData(res)
          console.log(res.status)
          history.push("/home")
        }
        else if(res.status === 400) {
          history.push("/login")
      }
          console.log(res.status)
      })
    }

    return (
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/twitter-logo-png/twitter-logo-vector-png-clipart-1.png" className="twitterlogo____image"/>
          <h1 className="login_____headertext">Log in to Twitter</h1>
          <div className="placeholder_____global">
          <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input className="placeholder____div" placeholder="Phone, email or username" onChange={onChangeUsername}/>
            <div>
              <input className="placeholder____div" placeholder="Password" type="password" onChange={onChangePassword}/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button className="twitter___loginbuttonpage" onClick={loginUser}>Log in</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            <div className="forgetPassword_____div">
              <p>Forgot password?</p>
              <p>·</p>
              <p>Sign up for Twitter</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

server side:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Users = require('../models/users.model.js')
const passport = require("passport")

require('../authentication/passportConfig.js')(passport)


router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  Users.find()
    .then(users => res.json(users))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error:' + err))
})


router.route('/login').post((req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local" , (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) res.status(400).send("No user exists");
    else {
      req.logIn(user, err => {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.status(200).send("Succesfully Authenticated")
      })
    }
  })(req, res, next)
})

router.route('/login').get((req, res) => {
  res.send(req.user)
})

router.route('/add').post(async(req,res) => {
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
  const username = req.body.username
  const password = hashedPassword
  const email = req.body.email
  const phone = req.body.phone
  const monthOfBirth = req.body.monthOfBirth
  const dayOfBirth = req.body.dayOfBirth
  const yearOfBirth = req.body.yearOfBirth

  const newUsers = new Users({
    username,
    password,
    email,
    phone,
    monthOfBirth,
    dayOfBirth,
    yearOfBirth
  })

  newUsers.save()
  .then (() => res.json("User Added"))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('error' + err))
})



module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing things up...
You have two different methods for the same purpose. If you use `onSubmit` in form, then you don't need to use `onClick` in the button.

You should completely remove `loginUser` function and move the logic to `onSubmit` method like following

```
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()

      const users = {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
      axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/login', users)
      .then(res => {
        if(res.status === 200) {
          setData(res)
          console.log(res.status)
          history.push("/home")
        }
        else if(res.status === 400) {
          history.push("/login")
      }
          console.log(res.status)
      })
    }
    }
```

also you can remove `onClick` handler from button, and set the button type to submit like following

```
   <div>
       <button className="twitter___loginbuttonpage" type="submit">Log in</button>
   </div>
```